# jar doesn't run after obfustication with ProGuard

Tags: java, proguard

I have app in jar file. I try to obfusticate it with ProGuard. In my ProGuard config file I have added:

```
-keep public class forms.Login{
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

After obfustication mapping file shows: forms.Login -> forms.Login:...void main(java.lang.String[]) -> main...

I run my app java -cp pathToObfusticatedJar.jar forms.Login, but I get error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 52
Exception Details:
  Location:
    forms/Login.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @0: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b800 904c 2bbe 3d03 3e1d 1ca2 0026 2b1d
    0x0000010: 323a 0412 0619 04b6 0093 b600 6499 000e
    0x0000020: 1904 b600 92b8 0091 a700 0984 0301 a7ff
    0x0000030: dba7 0050 4c12 0db6 0061 b800 68b2 003f
    0x0000040: 012b b600 69a7 003c 4c12 0db6 0061 b800
    0x0000050: 68b2 003f 012b b600 69a7 0028 4c12 0db6
    0x0000060: 0061 b800 68b2 003f 012b b600 69a7 0014
    0x0000070: 4c12 0db6 0061 b800 68b2 003f 012b b600
    0x0000080: 69bb 0013 59b7 005a b800 5fb1
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 49] => handler: 52
    bci [0, 49] => handler: 72
    bci [0, 49] => handler: 92
    bci [0, 49] => handler: 112

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Could someone be so kind to explain what I am doing wrong? Do I have to change proguard configuration or somehow set main method in cmd?
Also, I believe that I have set to keep my public static void main method, but Proguard chenges it. Why? How to make it stay unchaged?

Comment: Simply don't. Even Fortune 100 companies do not obfuscate their JARs.

Comment: I want to somehow secure my app, because there is login and password in it to my remote database. I use hibernate config and there are hibernate.connection.username and hibernate.connection.password in app.

Comment: You are doing it wrong if you need to store username and password inside your code. Have your application user authenticate on a web page and generate some sort of token for the user to use instead of username and password. Funnel your data via some web API instead of directly into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have disabled `preverification` which is necessary when running java applications on Java 7+.

Check your configuration and remove `-dontpreverify`.